# 2 Dimension Array in ColdFusion

Tags: arrays, dictionary, coldfusion

I'm trying to have a 2 dimension array in ColdFusion or a dictionary.

I'm reading from the database:

```
<cfquery name="getData" datasource="myDB">
    Select Name, Score From Customer
</cfquery>
```

I have a loop in this query. My query will return 6 records like this:

```
Test1, 3
Test2, 0
Test1, 1
Test3, 1
Test3, 3
Test2, 0
```

I would like to have this data in an array/dictionary where the names won't repeat the Scores will be added. In this case three 2 dimension arrays:

```
myArray(Test1, 4)
myArray(Test2, 0)
myArray(Test3, 4)
```

Is it possible in ColdFusion?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's no particular reason for using an array, you could also use a Struct.

This would look like the following:

```
<cfset myStruct = {} >
<cfloop query="getData">
  <cfif NOT StructKeyExists(myStruct,Name)>
    <cfset myStruct[Name] = [] >
  </cfif>
  <cfset ArrayAppend(myStruct[Name],score) > 
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Seems more complicated than necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You could always change your query to:

```
select name, sum(score) totalScore
from customer
group by name
```

Or, if you actually need the individual records, you could do a query of queries.

Comment: Thanks. Actually sometimes I have to read the data from a text file instead of a query.